# Identify gaps in time data

Tags: r, function, time, intervals

EDIT:

I found a way for the problem below, however, it works on a small dataset but still creates falses output on large datasets. Someone knows why? I can't find the mistake. Here's the code:

```
df$continuous <-
  unlist(lapply(split(df, df$ID),
                function(x) {
                  sapply(1:nrow(x),
                         function(y) {
                           any(x$start[y] - x$end[-(y:NROW(x$end))] <= 1)
                         })
                }))
```

ORIGINAL PROBLEM:
I'm working on a function to identify a gap in a series of start/end dates. The output should be FALSE if a start date begins later than 1 day after any of the previous end dates.

DATA:

```
df <- data.frame('ID' = c('1','1','1','1','1','1'), 'start' = as.Date(c('2010-01-01', '2010-01-03', '2010-01-05', '2010-01-09','2010-02-01', '2010-02-10')),
                 'end' = as.Date(c('2010-01-03', '2010-01-22', '2010-01-07', '2010-01-12', '2010-02-10', '2010-02-12')))
```

This is my attempt to solve this with `x = start` and `y = end`:

```
my_fun <- function(x,y){
  any(x[i] - y[1:NROW(i)-1] <= 1)
}
```

It works well if I specify `i` but I don't manage to wrap this into a loop. Ultimately, this function should be applied to groups in a large dataset in a `dplyr` manner.

This is what it should look like:

```
  ID      start        end  continuous
1  1 2010-01-01 2010-01-03 FALSE #or TRUE
2  1 2010-01-03 2010-01-22 TRUE
3  1 2010-01-05 2010-01-07 TRUE
4  1 2010-01-09 2010-01-12 TRUE
5  1 2010-02-01 2010-02-10 FALSE
6  1 2010-02-10 2010-02-12 TRUE #according to my function or FALSE compared to start[1] would be even better
```

I'd very much appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `dplyr` and `lubridate`. `dplyr` has really useful [window functions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html) like `lag()` that are handy for this type of analysis.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(start - lag(end, 1) == 0)

# ID      start        end start - lag(end, 1) == 0
# 1  1 2010-01-01 2010-01-03                       NA
# 2  1 2010-01-03 2010-01-22                     TRUE
# 3  1 2010-01-05 2010-01-07                    FALSE
# 4  1 2010-01-09 2010-01-12                    FALSE
# 5  1 2010-02-01 2010-02-10                    FALSE
# 6  1 2010-02-10 2010-02-12                     TRUE
```

How do you want to handle the first row of your data? Since there is no previous value, it shows `NA`. This is generally how you should handle situations like this but I can edit my answer if you'd like it to have a different value.

Comment: I also tried this approach before, however, I need a solution comparing the start dateT with all end dates prior to this point. So something like: 'start[4] - end[1:3]' The lag-function is therefore not enough unfortunately.

Comment: @ceefel could you arrange the data and then use a `lag()` or are there overlapping periods for the rows?

Comment: Right, the periods are overlapping. Start[1] until end[4] are actually one period. So start[5] should return FALSE

Comment: @AndrewBrēza is there a way to implement this line of code to evaluate the time gaps within a single column of timestamps rather than a start and end column?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I just re-read your question... and you wanted to compare the start with all the end dates. Then try to use the function expand.grid

```
df <- data.frame('ID' = c('1','1','1','1','1','1'), 'start' = as.Date(c('2010-01-01', '2010-01-03', '2010-01-05', '2010-01-09','2010-02-01', '2010-02-10')),
                 'end' = as.Date(c('2010-01-03', '2010-01-22', '2010-01-07', '2010-01-12', '2010-02-10', '2010-02-12')))

df_expand <- as.data.table(expand.grid(df$start,df$end))
```

This creates all the combinations between start/end

```
names(df_expand) = c("start","end")
df_expand[,ID:= 1]
df_expand[,diff_days := difftime(end,start,unit = "days")]
df_expand[,acceptable := any(diff_days<1), by = start]
```

Here we define what is acceptable..

```
df = merge(df,df_expand,by = c("start","end","ID"),all.x=TRUE)
```

I thought.. we might want to keep the original data, so we merge it back and shrink the information that we have.

Wait.. can you provide a proper example of what you expect and what is needed? I just read your other comment and now it confuses me...