# How to flag gaps in time data

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate

I am trying to create a flag for identifying gaps in timestamp data of more than 2 days.  [This question almost accomplishes what I need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45676209/identify-gaps-in-time-data) but my time data is in a single column rather than a start and end column. Also, I am using `data.table`.  Right now I am trying with `diff()` but I think this can probably be accomplished with `lag()` like in the linked question.

So far I have this:

```
library(data.table)

myID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
BST <- c("2017-06-01 00:00:01", "2017-06-01 00:00:02",
         "2017-06-02 00:00:01", "2017-06-02 00:00:02", 
         "2017-06-03 00:00:01", "2017-06-03 00:00:02",
         "2017-06-01 00:00:01", "2017-06-01 00:00:02", 
         "2017-06-05 00:00:01", "2017-06-05 00:00:02", 
         "2017-06-09 00:00:01", "2017-06-09 00:00:02")
dt1 <- data.table(myID, BST)

# Create gapFlag
dt1 <- dt1[, gapFlag := lapply(.SD, function(x) which(as.duration(diff(dt1$BTS))/ddays(1) > 2)), by = myID]
```

But that seems to run endlessly...  my actual data.table is upwards of 10 million rows.

My desired result looks like this (with the added bonus of counting the gaps in gapCount):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach using `diff`, which also gives `gapCount`:

```
library(data.table)

dt1[, gapFlag := c(0, diff(as.Date(BST)))>2, by = myID][, gapCount := cumsum(gapFlag), by = myID]
```

**Result:**

```
    myID                 BST gapFlag gapCount
 1:    1 2017-06-01 00:00:01   FALSE        0
 2:    1 2017-06-01 00:00:02   FALSE        0
 3:    1 2017-06-02 00:00:01   FALSE        0
 4:    1 2017-06-02 00:00:02   FALSE        0
 5:    1 2017-06-03 00:00:01   FALSE        0
 6:    1 2017-06-03 00:00:02   FALSE        0
 7:    2 2017-06-01 00:00:01   FALSE        0
 8:    2 2017-06-01 00:00:02   FALSE        0
 9:    2 2017-06-05 00:00:01    TRUE        1
10:    2 2017-06-05 00:00:02   FALSE        1
11:    2 2017-06-09 00:00:01    TRUE        2
12:    2 2017-06-09 00:00:02   FALSE        2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach with lagging

```
dt1[, l_BST := shift(BST), by = myID]
```

You can then compare the two columns depending on what your definition of a "gap" is (e.g. > 2 days between the two, with no NA values in either).

If you want to use `diff()` and stay within data.table (i.e. no other packages), you can do that too:

```
dt1[, gapFlag := c(0, diff(as.Date(BST))) > 2, by = myID]
dt1[, GapCount := cumsum(gapFlag), by = myID]
```